# Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me to prove this trigonometric equation.

$\cos \left( 36^\circ \right)-\cos \left( 72^\circ \right) = \frac{1}{2}$

Thank you.

Comment: This is the same question as: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130817/how-do-we-prove-cos-pi-5-cos2-pi-5-0-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $\displaystyle\cos(180^\circ-y)=-\cos y$

$$S=\cos36^\circ-\cos72^\circ=\cos36^\circ+\cos(180^\circ-108^\circ)=\cos36^\circ+\cos108^\circ$$

Now multiplying the numerator & the denominator by $\displaystyle2\sin\frac{(108-36)}2^\circ,$

$$S=\frac{2\sin36^\circ\cos36^\circ+2\sin36^\circ\cos108^\circ}{2\sin36^\circ}$$

Using [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) & $\sin2x$ formula,
$$S=\frac{\sin72^\circ+\sin144^\circ-\sin72^\circ}{2\sin36^\circ}=\frac{\sin(180^\circ-36^\circ)}{2\sin36^\circ}$$

Hope you can take it home from here

Comment: because $sin(180-36)=sin(\pi-\alpha)=sin(\alpha)=sin(36)$

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: @xzatulx, I've added two answers here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130817/how-do-we-prove-cos-pi-5-cos2-pi-5-0-5/830691#830691  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130817/how-do-we-prove-cos-pi-5-cos2-pi-5-0-5/830902#830902

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thank you for this answer, I think that it should be "multiplying numerator and denominator by $2\sin 36°$".

Comment: @Vasya Note that $\frac{(108-36)}2^{\circ}=36^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 4):

From a recent post which relates to the above trig functions at the given angles, we have:

$\cos36^{\circ} = \sin54^{\circ} = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}$, and:

$\cos72^{\circ} = \sin18^{\circ} = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$. Thus:

$\cos36^{\circ} - \cos72^{\circ} = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4} - \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: If you could give me the link for the trig functions at the given angles? Thank you.

Comment: @xzatulx: you can type my username and scroll down the posts and find the one with "trig equations".

Comment: Or, you can see this: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml