# Why is it that $\frac{\sin 30}{\sin 18}$ is equal to the golden ratio?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, golden-ratio

If you calculate $\frac{\sin 30}{\sin 18}$, where $18$ and $30$ are in degrees, the result is $\phi$, or alternately $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

I know that these numbers add up, but is there any specific reason for this occurrence?

**Note:**
I discovered this in a Physics lesson, when we were studying refractive indexes, which are calculated using the formula $\frac{\sin i}{\sin r}$.

It was a coincidence that, at the time, I was discussing the Fibonacci sequence with my friend, and showing her that if you take two numbers, and calculate the next number in the series by adding the previous two numbers, like in the Fibonacci sequence, as the numbers tend toward infinity, the ratio between any two consecutive numbers in the sequence is $\phi$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want a proof that $\frac{\sin (30)}{\sin (18)}=\phi$ or is it something? If something else, what?

Comment: I am sorry if my question is unclear, but I was wondering if there was any reason to this, except that they add up.

It is a strange question, and I am sorry if I have misled you.

Comment: Use a specific formula for the area of a triangle.$E=1/2\cdot a\cdot b \cdot sin C$. Compare two areas together.

Comment: Is this formula already known, and if not, does it have any useful implications? @GitGud

Comment: I still have no idea what you want. To me a 'reason' is a proof. But the whole demeanor of the question suggests you're more interested not in a proof but in the intuition behind this equality. I am left then with two different interpretations of the question.

Comment: I believe that the latter is what I am asking for. @GitGud

Comment: @Taylor Given that $\sin(30^\circ)$ is just $\frac12$, there are simpler ways of writing this.  But it _does_ have implications; searching on 'golden ratio pentagon' (as $\sin(18^\circ)=-\cos(108^\circ)$ and $108^\circ$ is the interior angle of a pentagon) should turn up some interesting information...

Comment: Oh, that is very interesting! Thank you very much! If you write this up as an answer, I will up-vote it. @StevenStadnicki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here it is a nice geometric proof. Let $ABCDE$ a regular pentagon, and $F$ a point on $AC$ such that $AF=AB$. By angle chasing, we have that $CFB$ is similar to $ABC$, hence:
$$ \frac{AC}{AB} = 1+\frac{CF}{AB} = 1+\frac{CF}{CB} = 1+\frac{AB}{AC}, $$
giving $\frac{AC}{AB}=\phi$. By applying the sine theorem to the triangle $ABC$ and the sine duplication formula we easily prove our claim.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin30^\circ=1/2$

If $y=\dfrac{\sin30^\circ}{\sin18^\circ}=\dfrac1{2\sin18^\circ},$

$$\frac1{4\sin^218^\circ}-\frac1{2\sin18^\circ}-1=\frac{1-2\sin18^\circ-4\sin^218^\circ}{4\sin^218^\circ}$$

$$=\frac{1-2\cos(90^\circ-18^\circ)-2(1-\cos36^\circ)}{4\sin^218^\circ}$$

$$=\frac{2(\cos36^\circ-\cos72^\circ)-1}{4\sin^218^\circ}=0$$

using [Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2)

$$\implies y^2-y-1=0$$

Now clearly $y>0$