# Show that $4\cos\frac\pi5\cdot\sin\frac\pi{10}=1$

Tags: trigonometry, roots-of-unity

We have to prove this identity : $$4\cos\frac\pi5\cdot\sin\frac\pi{10}=1$$
The book's hint is we somehow find out that $\displaystyle1+2\left(\cos\frac\pi5-\cos\frac{2\pi}5\right)$ equals something (from the geometry of a regular pentagon) and the result follows. But I can neither see why the book's hint is true nor how it could yield a result for the original problem. So could you help me proving it either by the book's hint or another way?

Comment: Thank you for the trigonometric answers but could you use a complex number approach?

Answer (score 1):

Given $\displaystyle 2\cos \frac{\pi}{5}\cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{10}\;,$ Now  Let $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{10} = \theta \;,$ and using $$ 2\sin A\cdot \cos A = \sin 2A$$

Then $$\displaystyle 2\cos 2\theta \cdot \sin \theta=\frac{2\cos 2\theta\cdot \sin \theta \cdot \cos \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{2\sin 2\theta \cdot \cos 2\theta}{2\cos \theta} =\frac{\sin 4\theta}{2\cos \theta}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{\sin 4 \theta}{2\cos \theta} = \frac{\sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{10}\right)}{2\cos \frac{\pi}{10}} = \frac{\cos \frac{\pi}{10}}{2\cos \frac{\pi}{10}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Bcz  $$\displaystyle \sin \frac{4\pi}{10} = \sin  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{10}\right) = \cos \frac{\pi}{10}$$

Comment: Why is $\sin(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$ between 2nd and 3rd term?

Comment: You get the much needed $\frac{1}{2}$ that way, because the solution is $\frac{1}{2}$, not 1 ;)

Comment: Thanks  Inuyaki I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html), $$2\cos36^\circ\sin18^\circ=\sin54^\circ-\sin18^\circ=\cos36^\circ-\cos72^\circ$$

Now see [Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Notice $$LHS=2\cos \frac{\pi}{5}\sin\frac{\pi}{10}$$
$$=2\cos 36^\circ \sin18^\circ$$  Setting the values of $\cos 36^\circ$ & $\sin 18^\circ$

$$=2\left(\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{4}\right)$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt 5+1)(\sqrt 5-1)}{8}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt 5)^2-1^2}{8}$$ $$=\frac{5-1}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Why is this a HINT ?   I have nothing left to solve on my own.