# Find the value of $\sin \dfrac {\pi}{10} - \sin \dfrac {3\pi}{10}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\sin \dfrac {\pi}{10} - \sin \dfrac {3\pi}{10}$

My Attempt:
$$\sin \dfrac {\pi}{10} - \sin \dfrac {3\pi}{10}$$
$$\sin \dfrac {180}{10} - \sin \dfrac {3\times 180}{10}$$
$$\sin 18^\circ - \sin 54^\circ$$

Now,

Let $A=18^\circ$.
$$5A=90^\circ$$
$$2A+3A=90^\circ$$
$$3A=90^\circ - 2A$$
Taking 'sin' on the both sides,
$$\sin 3A=\sin (90^\circ - 2A)$$
$$3\sin A-4\sin^3 A=\cos 2A$$

What should I do further?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin \dfrac {\pi}{10} - \sin \dfrac {3\pi}{10}=\cos72^{\circ}+\cos144^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{2\sin36^{\circ}\cos72^{\circ}+2\sin36^{\circ}\cos144^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin108^{\circ}-\sin36^{\circ}+\sin180^{\circ}-\sin108^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Done!

Comment: How did you get $\dfrac {-1}{2}$? Could you show the calculations?

Comment: @Ramanujan It was typo. See now, please.

Answer (score 2):

$\cos 2A=1-2\sin^2 A$, then substitute $x=\sin A$.