# If $x=2\sin\frac{3\pi}{10}$, find the value of the expression.

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots, quadratics, factoring

If $x=2\sin\frac{3\pi}{10}$, find the value of the expression
$$
W =2x^5+x^4-4x^3-4x^2-x+7
$$
After a bit of thought, I got :
$$
x = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
$$
But I don't think my teacher expected me to substitute the value of $x$ into the expression. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: Absolutely, you won't substitute that value into the expression

Comment: Even without know the value of $2\sin\dfrac{3\pi}{10}$  using  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2, $$\dfrac x2=2\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2-1+\dfrac12\iff x^2-x-1=0$$ So, $$2\sin\dfrac\pi{10}$$ will be another root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $x^2-x-1=0$. It must help:
$$2x^5+x^4-4x^3-4x^2+x+7=(x^2-x-1)(2x^3+3x^2+x)+7=7.$$

Comment: you just made an edit, you gave a factor $(x^2 - x + 1) $ which differs form $x^2 - x - 1.$ I just revised the question to what I think was intended by the people/book asking

Comment: @Will Jagy It was typo. Thank you!