# Trigonometric Equation : $\sin 96^\circ \sin 12^\circ \sin x = \sin 18^\circ \sin 42^\circ \sin (12^\circ -x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Please help solving this equation:

$\sin 96^\circ \sin 12^\circ \sin x = \sin 18^\circ \sin 42^\circ \sin (12^\circ -x)$

I used numerical method to solve it and got $x=6^\circ$ but I am not able  to solve it by trigonmetry.

Thank!
Best Regards, Michael.

Comment: Can you add to your post the method you used to solve it numerically?

Comment: Just by calculator.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same observation as @dantopa we get

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin(x) &=& \sin(12^\circ - x )\\
\sin(x) &=& \sin(12^\circ)\cos(x)-\cos(12^\circ)\sin(x)\\
\tan(x) &=& \sin(12^\circ)-\cos(12^\circ)\tan(x)\\
\tan(x)(1+\cos(12^\circ))&=&\sin(12^\circ)\\
\tan(x)&=&\frac{\sin(12^\circ)}{1+\cos(12^\circ)}\\
\tan(x)&=&\tan(6^\circ)\\
x &=& 6^\circ+180^\circ n
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: We can use $$x=n180^\circ+(-1)^n(12^\circ-x)$$ as well

Answer (score 0):

Hint: have you tried using the product-to-sum identities? That is, $$ \sin A\sin B =\frac{1}{2}(\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)) $$ is one such formula. Note that there are several formulas of this type that can be used here. The rightmost term $\sin(12^{\circ}-x)$ can also be simplified by using a similar formula and solving for the $\sin(A-B)$ term.

Comment: I attempted to show that $\sin 96^0 \sin 12^0 = \sin 18^0 \sin 42^0$ but I needed to use the values of special angles. Here I will show my work and please let me know if there is a better method.

Comment: $\sin 96^0 \sin 12^0 - \sin 18^0 \sin 42^0$
$=\frac 12 ( \cos 84^0 - \cos 108^0)-\frac 12 ( \cos 24^0 -\cos 60^0)$
$=\frac 12 ( \cos 84^0 - \cos 24^0)+ \frac 12 ( \cos 60^0 - \cos 108^0)$
$=-\sin 54^0 \sin 30^0 + \frac 12 (\cos 60^0 - \cos 108^0)$
$=-\frac 12 \sin 54^0+ \frac 12 ( \frac 12 - \cos 108^0)$
$=\frac 14 - \frac 12( \sin 54^0 - \cos 72^0)$
$=\frac 14 -   \frac 12 ( \sin 54^0 - \sin 18^0)$
$= \frac 14 - \frac 12 ( \frac {\sqrt{5}+1}2-\frac {\sqrt{5}-1})$
$=\frac 14 - \frac 12 \times \frac 12 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Observation**
$$
 \sin 96^{\circ} \sin 12^{\circ} =  \sin 18^{\circ} \sin 42^{\circ} 
$$

**Implication**
$$
 \sin x = \sin \left(12^{\circ} - x \right) \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = 12^{\circ} - x 
$$

**Conclusion**

> $$x=6^{\circ}$$

Comment: `Implication` The sine function is not injective, for example $x=186^\circ$ is a solution as well.

Comment: @dxiv: of course we can add and subtract integer multiples of $\pi$. The structure of the problem suggests the answer given.

Comment: I don't see what in the problem suggests that $6^\circ$ would be a "*better*" answer than, say, $186^\circ$. `of course we can add and subtract integer multiples of π` That belongs into the answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @dantopa, I'm really interested in the proof of the $1$st proposition. I could utilize https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2 to prove it