# Prove that $\cos24^\circ\cos84^\circ=\cos^2 72^\circ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, radicals, nested-radicals

I simplified this to:

$\sqrt {150+30\sqrt 5} + 14 + 9\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5}=
10\sqrt5+\sqrt{30+6\sqrt5} + 2\sqrt{30-6\sqrt5}+\sqrt{30-10
\sqrt5}$

any thoughts

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that
$$\cos108^{\circ}+\cos60^{\circ}=1+\cos144^{\circ}$$ or
$$\cos108^{\circ}-\cos144^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$2\sin18^{\circ}\sin126^{\circ}=\frac{1}{4}$$ or
$$\sin18^{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}=\frac{1}{4}$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\cdot\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4}=\frac{1}{4},$$
which is obvious.

Id est, your statement is true.

Done!

About your identity.

We need to prove that
$$\sqrt {150+30\sqrt 5} + 14 + 9(\sqrt5-1)=
10\sqrt5+\sqrt{30+6\sqrt5} + 2\sqrt{30-6\sqrt5}+\sqrt5(\sqrt5-1)$$ or
$$\sqrt {150+30\sqrt 5}=\sqrt{30+6\sqrt5} + 2\sqrt{30-6\sqrt5}$$ or
$$150+30\sqrt5=30+6\sqrt5+4\sqrt{(30+6\sqrt5)(30-6\sqrt5)}+4(30-6\sqrt5)$$ or
$$48\sqrt5=4\sqrt{900-180}.$$
Done!

Comment: OK cute but what about the above equation

Comment: @Howard I think there is a mistake in your computations. $LS-RS=-2.288...$

Comment: 39.85831599 for both

Comment: @Howard See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt+%7B150%2B30%5Csqrt+5%7D+%2B+14+%2B+9%5Csqrt%7B6-2%5Csqrt5%7D-(10%5Csqrt5%2B%5Csqrt%7B30%2B6%5Csqrt5%7D+%2B+2%5Csqrt%7B30-6%5Csqrt5%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B30-2%5Csqrt5%7D)

Comment: found and corrected my typo

Comment: $$\cos108^\circ-\cos144^\circ=\cos(180-144)^\circ-\cos(180-108)^\circ=?$$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I think In math all problems are duplicate because they are math problems. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the sum to product formula for the left hand side...

$$\cos \alpha \cos \beta = \frac {cos (\alpha - \beta) + \cos (\alpha + \beta)}{2}$$

Then use the power reduction formula for cosine on the right hand side...

$$\cos^2 \alpha = \frac {1 + \cos 2 \alpha}{2}$$

Comment: Yes I got that very elegant but I am interested with working with the radicals perhaps I need a different question

Comment: Perhaps the title should  have been Derived from cos(24)cos(84)=