# Help with trigonometric proof

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that  $\frac {\cos (24)}{\cos {6} }+2\times \sin {24}=\sqrt {3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\cos24^{\circ}+2\sin24^{\circ}\cos6^{\circ}=2\sin60^{\circ}\cos6^{\circ}$$ or
$$\cos24^{\circ}+\sin30^{\circ}+\sin18^{\circ}=\sin66^{\circ}+\sin54^{\circ}$$ or
$$\sin66^{\circ}+\frac{1}{2}+\sin18^{\circ}=\sin66^{\circ}+\sin54^{\circ}$$ or
$$\sin54^{\circ}-\sin18^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2},$$ which is true because
$$\sin54^{\circ}-\sin18^{\circ}=2\sin18^{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}=2\cos36^{\circ}\cos72^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{4\sin36^{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}\cos72^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}=\frac{2\sin72^{\circ}\cos72^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin144^{\circ}}{2\sin36^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution a bit more please?

Comment: @user373141 I added something. See now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg   thanks from heart

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: see that $$\cos(6)=\cos(30-24)=\cos(30)\cos(24)+\sin(30)\sin(24) =\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\cos(24) +\frac{1}2\sin(24)$$

Comment: @thanks a lot,  but how can I get $\cos {24} , \sin{24}$ ?