# What is the value of $\sin^2 (\frac{\pi}{10}) \sin^2 (\frac{3\pi}{10})$?

Tags: trigonometry, fractions, products

> **PROBLEM**
>   $$ \prod_{i=0}^4 \left(1 + \cos \left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{10}\right)\right)$$

**My Try**
$$
\left(1 + \cos \frac{\pi}{10}\right)
\left(1 + \cos \frac{9\pi}{10}\right)
\left(1 + \cos \frac{7\pi}{10}\right)
\left(1 + \cos \frac{3\pi}{10}\right)
= \sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)
  \sin^2 \left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)
$$

I am not able to proceed further. 
Please help me.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sin^2 {\frac {\pi}{10}} \sin^2 \frac {3\pi}{10}=\left(\frac {4\sin {\frac {\pi}{5}}. \cos {\frac {2\pi}{10}}\cos {\frac {4\pi}{10}}}{4\sin \frac {\pi}{5}}\right)^2=\left(\frac {\sin \frac {4\pi}{5}}{4\sin \frac {\pi}{5}}\right)^2=\frac {1}{16}$$

Comment: Why the hell was this downvoted. It is the best anyone can think of(+1)

Comment: Upvoted. The use of degrees is irrelevant to the validity (and elegance) of this solution.

Comment: @Deepak I hope this makes it better

Comment: @Manthanein I don't know that it does. It was fine before. Some unreasonable people downvoted simply because of the use of degrees. I thought it was a lot easier to *see* it in degrees.

Comment: @Manthanein Anyway, you've taken the effort, it isn't wrong by any means and if Michael's fine with it, then let it be.

Comment: I think with degrees it seems better, but if  Manthanein wishes...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg No just don't think of my wishes.  Keep the way you like it.  I loved the answer really very much and couldn't help seeing the downvotes. On seeing comments I saw that that it was downvoted because of the degree thing and I couldn't accept it.  So I edited it. But you can keep the way you wish it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of $\Phi_{10}(x)=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4$ are the primitive tenth roots of unity, $\xi,\xi^3,\xi^7,\xi^9$ with $\xi=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{10}\right)$. The roots of $\Phi_{20}(x)=\Phi_{10}(x^2)=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8$ are the primitive $20$-th roots of unity, $\zeta,\zeta^3,\zeta^7,\zeta^9,\zeta^{11},\zeta^{13},\zeta^{17},\zeta^{19}$ with $\zeta=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{10}\right)$. By dividing $\Phi_{20}(x)$ by $x^4$ and by writing what we get as a polynomial in $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ we get that

$$ x^4-\frac{5}{4}x^2+\frac{5}{16}=\prod_{k\in\{1,3,7,9\}}\left(x-\cos\frac{\pi k}{10}\right)$$
and by evaluating both sides at $x=-1$ we get:
$$ \prod_{k\in\{1,3,7,9\}}\left(1+\cos\frac{\pi k}{10}\right) = 1-\frac{5}{4}+\frac{5}{16} = \frac{1}{16}.$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}$$

Comment: yes it was just a typo! thank you for your hint!