# Find the exact value of trigonometric expression: $ \arctan\frac{2\cos \frac{\pi}{30} \cos\frac{\pi}{15}}{1+2\cos \frac{\pi}{30} \sin\frac{\pi}{15}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

How can I simplify this trigonometric expression?

> $$  \arctan\frac{2\cos \frac{\pi}{30} \cos\frac{\pi}{15}}{1+2\cos \frac{\pi}{30} \sin\frac{\pi}{15}}$$

I used

$$\sin \frac{\pi}{15}=2 \sin \frac{\pi}{30}  \cos \frac{\pi}{30}$$ and $$\cos\frac{\pi}{15}=2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{30}-1$$

But these give me more complicated expressions.

Comment: What is the source of this uncommon problem?

Comment: I find the answer is $\dfrac{3\pi}{10}$ by wolfram alpha

Comment: Reminds me of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805023/how-to-prove-dfrac1-sin6-circ-cos12-circ-cos6-circ-sin12-circ

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  A contest math problem.(in the book) I could not solve.  (I tried for hours) WA can solve ,but unfortunately, doesnt show steps. So, I shared problem here.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee   Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Do you think there is an elegant way?

Comment: @Elementary, I need more time & concentration which  I'm really sorry that I could not invest. I will be really happy to solve it. Thanks for the nice problem. Pray continue supplying such problems

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'll just be happy, to learn from your wisdom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\arctan\left(\dfrac{2\cos6^\circ\cos12^\circ}{1+2\cos6^\circ\sin12^\circ}\right)=y,-90^\circ<y<90^\circ$

$\implies\dfrac{2\cos6^\circ\cos12^\circ}{1+2\cos6^\circ\sin12^\circ}=\tan y=\dfrac{\sin y}{\cos y}$

Rearranging we get $$\cos(6^\circ+y)+\cos(18^\circ+y)=\sin y=\cos(90^\circ-y)$$

$$\iff\cos(90^\circ-y)=\cos(18^\circ+y)+\cos(6^\circ+y)=2\cos6^\circ\cos(12^\circ+y)\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Like [Solve equation $\tan(x)=\sec(42^\circ)+\sqrt{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354759/solve-equation-tanx-sec42-circ-sqrt3/3364519#3364519)

using [Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2)

$$\cos36^\circ=\cos72^\circ+\cos60^\circ=2\cos6^\circ\cos66^\circ\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Compare $(1),(2)$

$$\frac{\cos36^\circ}{\cos(90^\circ-y)}=\dfrac{2\cos6^\circ\cos66^\circ}{2\cos6^\circ\cos(12^\circ+y)}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{\cos(12^\circ+y)}{\cos(90^\circ-y)}=\dfrac{\cos66^\circ}{\cos36^\circ}$$

Apply [Componendo et Dividendo](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm) and [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) to find

$$\tan(y-39^\circ)=\tan15^\circ$$

The rest should be easy!

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}
T &= \large \left(\frac{2\cos 6° \cos 12°}{1\;+\;2\cos 6° \sin 12°}\right)
\left({2\sin 6° \over 2\sin 6°}\right)\cr 
&= \large \frac{\sin 24°}{2\sin 6°+\;2\sin^2 12°}\cr\cr
{1\over T}&= \large \frac{2\sin(30°-24°)+\;(1-\cos 24°)}{\sin 24°}\cr
&=\large {(\cos 24° - \sqrt3\sin24°) + (1-\cos 24°) \over \sin 24°}\cr
&=\large{1\over\sin(60°-36°)} - \sqrt3 \cr
&=\large{4\over 2\sqrt3 \cos36° - 2\sin 36°}-\sqrt3 \cr
\end{align}$

From wikipedia on [Golden triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_triangle_(mathematics)), 
$\quad2\cos(36°)=\phi,\quad 2\sin(36°)=\sqrt{4-\phi^2}$

$\begin{align}
\large{1\over T}&=\left({4\over \sqrt3\phi-\sqrt{4-\phi^2}}\right)
\left({\sqrt3\phi+\sqrt{4-\phi^2} \over \sqrt3\phi+\sqrt{4-\phi^2}} \right)
-\sqrt3 \cr
&= {4(\sqrt3\phi + \sqrt{4-\phi^2}) \over 3\phi^2-(4-\phi^2)} -\sqrt3 \cr
&= {\sqrt3\phi + \sqrt{4-\phi^2} \over \phi^2-1}-\sqrt3 \cr
&= {\sqrt3\phi + \sqrt{4-\phi^2} \over \phi} -\sqrt3 \cr
&= {\sqrt{4-\phi^2} \over \phi} = \tan(36°)
\end{align}$

$$T = \tan(90°-36°) = \tan(54°)$$

Answer (score 0):

The identity can also be proved from: $\quad\cos36° = \cos 72° + {1\over2}$

$\cos 72° + {1\over2}= (2\cos^2 36° - 1)+ {1\over2}\;= \large{\phi^2\over2}-{1\over2} ={\phi \over 2}=\cos36°$

---

$T= \Large \frac{2\cos 6° \cos 12°}{1\;+\;2\cos 6° \sin 12°}$

$\Large{1\over T} = {1\over 2\cos 6° \cos 12°} + \normalsize \tan 12°$

$\begin{align} \tan 36° - \tan12° 
&= {\sin36° \over \cos36°} - {\sin12° \over \cos12°} \cr
&= {\sin36° \cos12° - \cos36° \sin12° \over \cos12° \cos36°} \cr
&= {\sin24° \over \cos12° (\cos72° + 0.5)} \cr
&= {\sin24° \over \cos12°(\sin18° + \sin30°)} \cr
&= {\sin24° \over \cos12°(2 \sin24° \cos6°)} \cr
\tan36° &= {1\over 2\cos 6° \cos 12°} + \tan12°
\end{align}$

$$T = \cot 36° = \tan 54°$$