# Solving $\frac{5}{8} \cot36^\circ = \cos^3x$ without substituting the trig values for $36^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

> Find the value of $x$ such that 
>   $$\frac{5}{8} \cot36^\circ = \cos^3x$$
>   The answer is $x=18^\circ$.

It's really messy to plug in the standard values of $\cos36^\circ$, $\sin36^\circ$ and miraculously guess a suitable value of $x$ and prove that our guess is correct.

> Is there any nice way to find the value of $x$?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+5%2F8cot%2836+degrees%29%3Dcos%5E3%28x+degrees%29+for+x+)?!

Comment: The problem is with the $5$ : I cannot think of standard formulae that can be used to get rid of the $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac58\cdot\cot36^\circ=\dfrac{5\cos36^\circ}{8\sin36^\circ}=\dfrac{5\cos^236^\circ}{4\cos18^\circ}$$

Using [Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2)

$$\cos36^\circ-(2\cos^236^\circ-1)=\frac12\iff5\cos^2 36^\circ=(1+\cos36^\circ)^2=(2\cos^218^\circ)^2$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\cos^3x=\frac{3\cos{x}+\cos{3x}}{4},$$ we need to prove that:
$$\frac{5\cos36^{\circ}}{8\sin36^{\circ}}=\frac{3\cos18^{\circ}+\cos54^{\circ}}{4}$$ or
$$5\cos36^{\circ}=3\sin54^{\circ}+3\sin18^{\circ}+\sin90^{\circ}-\sin18^{\circ}$$ or
$$2\cos36^{\circ}+2\cos108^{\circ}=1,$$ which is true because
$$2\cos36^{\circ}+2\cos108^{\circ}=\frac{2\sin36^{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}+2\sin36^{\circ}\cos108^{\circ}}{\sin36^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin72^{\circ}+\sin144^{\circ}-\sin72^{\circ}}{\sin36^{\circ}}=1.$$

Comment: Very nice solution +1. It's really tough to decide who to choose as the accepted answer. I am going with Lab bhattacarjee's answer as there was no "reverse solution" and it appeared a bit more "one way" although your solution is more natural

Comment: And pls don't reverse the steps of the solution for that, it would spoil its essence :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet an other way to proceed, using algebraic only manipulations after a quick reshape...

We want to show
$$
\frac 58\cdot \frac{\cos 36^\circ}{\sin 36^\circ}
\overset{!}=\sin^3 72^\circ \ .
$$
Let us denote by $c,s$ respectively the values for $\cos 36^\circ$ and $\sin 36^\circ$. Then we want:
$$
\frac 58\cdot\frac cs 
\overset{!}=
8s^3c^3\ ,\text{ or equivalently }
5 - 64s^4c^2=0\ .
$$
We start with $(s+ic)^5=\cos (5\cdot 36^\circ)+i\sin(5\cdot 36^\circ)=-1$, and consider only the imaginary part, thus getting
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
0 
&= 5sc^4-10s^3c^2+s^5\ ,\text{ and since $s\ne 0$ we get}\\
0 &= 5c^4-10s^2c^2+s^4\\
&=5(1-2s^2+s^4)-10s^2(1-s^2)+s^4\\
&=5-20s^2+16s^4\ .
\qquad\text{From here:}
\\[3mm]
5-64s^4c^2
&=5 - 64s^4(1-s^2)
\\&=
5-64s^4+64s^6\\
&=\underbrace{(5-20s^2+16s^4)}_{=0}(1+4s^2)=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$