# Evaluating $\cos24^\circ-\cos84^\circ-\cos12^\circ+\sin42^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

How to evaluate:
$$\cos24^\circ-\cos84^\circ-\cos12^\circ+\sin42^\circ$$
Can somebody help me handle it?
I have no idea what to do.

This is my attempt:

$$\cos24^\circ-\cos(60^\circ+24^\circ)-\cos12^\circ+\sin (12^\circ+30^\circ)$$

Comment: If you just need the solution, it's $0.5$. However I'm not confident about how to prove that.

Comment: @SarGe I think the answer is to be approximated

Comment: Never mind. I looked at its solution. I just wanted to know how to prove it

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, everything is correct

Comment: use $\cos C - \cos D$ in the first two terms and sinC- sinD in the last 2....you'll get sin36 and cos54 as major unknowns, which should be very close to sin37 and cos53, unless you want to substitute sin36 and cos56

Comment: @SarGe yes, it maybe possible, so better put the value of sin36

Comment: Now, i tried to make sin42° = cos48°. As a result, all of them became cos, but i couldn't go further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111652/discussion-between-usmonbek-gokhan-and-anindya-prithvi).

Comment: @USmonbekGo'khan there's an answer for cos tooo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111718/discussion-between-usmonbek-gokhan-and-anindya-prithvi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try proving $\sin (18°)=\frac {\sqrt{5}-1}4 $

Hint : If $\theta=18°$ Then $5\theta=90°$

So $2\theta=90°-3\theta$

$\Rightarrow \sin(2\theta)=\cos (3\theta) $   and so on.

With the help of $\sin (18°) $, find $\sin (54°) $

Now ,

$\cos 24-\cos 84=2\sin 54 \sin 30$

$\cos 12-\sin 42=\cos 12-\cos 48$

$\quad \quad \quad \quad =2\sin (30) \sin (18)$

So the required value is

$\sin (54°)-\sin (18°)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{split}
\cos24^\circ-\cos84^\circ-\cos12^\circ+\sin42^\circ  &= \cos24^\circ-\cos84^\circ-\cos12^\circ+\cos48^\circ\\
&= \cos24^\circ +\cos48^\circ-\cos84^\circ-\cos12^\circ \\
&= 2\cos36^\circ\cos12^\circ-2\cos48^\circ\cos36^\circ\\
&=2\cos36^\circ(\cos12^\circ-\cos48^\circ)\\
&=2\cos36^\circ(2\sin18^\circ\sin30^\circ)\\
&=\frac{(2\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ)2\cos36^\circ\sin30^\circ}{\cos18^\circ}\\
&= \frac{(2\sin36^\circ\cos36^\circ)\sin30^\circ}{\cos18^\circ}\\
&=\frac{\sin72^\circ\sin30^\circ}{\cos18^\circ}\\
&=\sin30^\circ=\frac{1}{2}
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$-\cos84^\circ-\cos96^\circ$$

$$-\cos12^\circ=\cos192^\circ=\cos168^\circ$$

$$\sin42^\circ=\cos(?)$$

As $\cos5x=-\dfrac12$ for  $x=120^\circ,240^\circ\equiv-120^\circ,480^\circ\equiv120^\circ,960^\circ\equiv-120^\circ\pmod{360^\circ}$

Now $\cos5x+\cos x=2\cos3x\cos2x$

$\cos5x=2(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)(2\cos^2x-1)=?$

So, the roots of $$16c^5-20c^3+16c+\dfrac12=0$$ are $5x=360^\circ n+120^\circ\iff x=72^\circ n+24^\circ; -2\le n\le2$

$$\sum_{n=-2}^2\cos(72^\circ n+24^\circ)=\dfrac0{16}$$

$$\implies\cos(-120)^\circ+\cos(-48^\circ)+\cos24^\circ+\cos96^\circ+\cos168^\circ=0$$