Finding a more efficient solution to a trigonometric identity problem.
THIS IS NOT A HOMEWORK QUESTION
This question comes from a university entrance exam from around 1910. No solutions were ever published. My own solution is given here, but I get the feeling that a more efficient solution would be possible.
Question: Find the exact value of $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{4\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{8\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{14\pi}{15}}$
My solution: Re-write the functions as $\cos{\frac{5\pi-3\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{9\pi-5\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{5\pi+3\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{9\pi+5\pi}{15}}$
Which simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{\frac{\pi}{5}}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{3\pi}{5}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{\frac{3\pi}{5}}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{\frac{\pi}{5}}++\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{3\pi}{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{\frac{3\pi}{5}}$
$=\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}+\cos{\frac{3\pi}{5}}$
$=2\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}\cos{\frac{2\pi}{5}}$
Now, because I know that $\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$ and $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{5}}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$ I can simplify this to $\frac{1}{2}$.
However, I wonder:
1 - would students in 1910 have known such exact values?
2 - is there a more efficient solution?
Sum-to-product and product-to-sum identities seem to be commonplace in exams at the time, so I am wondering if there is a clever application of these that I have missed.
Thoughts appreciated as always.

Can you specify which university? And was it an entrance exam or a scholarship exam?

University of Melbourne, but they set the papers for the whole of the state of Victoria at the time. The students sitting the paper would have been anywhere from 16 to 19 years old. Any student applying to a Victorian university would have sat the paper. I can get the actual year if you want.

I wonder whether there was a "syllabus". When trying to understand the background of these old questions I have usually looked at the textbooks of the time.

I was wrong - the earliest usage of this question I can find was from a University of Cambridge entrance examination. A book published in 1904 had a collection of past papers for students to use to prepare. This was in one of those papers. The book was compiled by EM Radford and I found it in a public library here in Melbourne.

As $\pi=180^\circ,$  use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

A couple of rounds of sum-to-product action can get you to
$$4\cos\frac{2\pi}{5};\cos\frac{\pi}{5};\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$$
without having to do any expansion. After the first round, in which you can pair terms however you like, you'll get a common factor.

Thanks @Blue - I was wondering if different pairings made the question easier/more difficult but really couldn't decide either way.

I think I once saw a copy of that book. I also believe that some of these Cambridge papers were taken by students already at university who wanted to win a scholarship at one of the colleges; so the level of the questions is very variable.

This might help, I’m not sure.  The integers in the numerators (2, 4, 8, 14) are almost a geometric progression.  BUT cos(14pi/15) = cos(16pi/15) and now we have a geometric progression.

@WillOctagonGibson - I was actually wondering if the opposite was true. 2,4,8,14 are coprime with 15, so maybe the pattern lies there. Of course, 7 and 11 would also be part of the pattern if that were the case, so I decided it was likely not.

The "pattern" is the ones coprime to $15$ of which there are eight :$\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8=\pm7$. As we are dealing with the cosine, the sign doesn't matter.

Fun fact with lots of sevens:  $(\tan(\pi/7))^6+(\tan(2\pi/7))^6+(\tan(3\pi/7))^6=7077$

I think that you have done it the way that a student in 1910 might have done it. I'm sure they'd know all about the geometry/trigonometry of the pentagon, so they'd know these values.
I think that nowadays it might be slicker to recall that $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$, and then observe that the quantity sought is half the sum of the primitive $15$-th roots of unity. Now that sum is, by inclusion/exclusion, the sum of all the $15$-th roots of unity less the sum of all the $5$-th roots of unity less the sum of all the $3$-rd roots of unity plus  the sum of all the $1$-st roots of unity: that is $0-0-0+1=1$.

Yes, I did wonder about the complex numbers solution as they were seen on-and-off in exams around the time. Unfortunately, I can't find any syllabus documents for the time, so it is difficult to know what was and was not actually taught to these students.

I love the fact that a user called ancient mathematician answered this question.

Better yet, the sum of primitive $15$th roots of unity is the Möbius function of $15$. As $15$ is square-free with an even number of prime factors this is $+1$.

@OscarLanzi Yes, Inclusion/Exclusion is just a special case of Moebius functions on lattices. See Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics e.g.

Once you have $2\cos(\pi/5)\cos(2\pi/5)$, continue:
$2\cos(\pi/5)\cos(2\pi/5)=\cos(3\pi/5)+\cos(\pi/5)$
$=-\cos(2\pi/5)+\cos(\pi/5)$
Now consider the sides of a regular pentagon $ABCDE$ as vectors arranged head to tail. Clearly these must have a zero resultant, and then taking the component parallel to side $AB$ gives
$1\underset{\text{sides BC, EA}}{\underbrace{+2\cos(2\pi/5)}}\underset{\text{sides CD, DE}}{\underbrace{-2\cos(\pi/5)}}=0.$
So
$2\cos(\pi/5)\cos(2\pi/5)=-\cos(2\pi/5)+\cos(\pi/5)=1/2,$
which is of course the answer. We did not need exact values of the pentagonal or decagonal angle cosines.
Students in 1910, and well before then, actually could have known the exact cosine values anyway. They may be derived from constructions involving the golden ratio, such as bisecting a base angle of an isosceles triangle when the base angles are each twice the apex angle, which have been known since the ancient Greeks. For that matter, the last equation above contains all the information needed to extract both cosine values; I will let the reader do so.

From your Question one can see that only coprime numbers to $15$ appear in the numerator $(2,4,8,14)$
Tempting to answer 2- is there a more efficient solution?
My thoughts suggest to look more towards number theory where for two primes $p,q$ we have for the sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i \mid \gcd(p q , i)=1}^{\lfloor \frac{p q}{2} \rfloor}{\cos{\frac{2 i \pi }{p q}}} = \frac{1}{2} \;\; \mid p>q>2 \end{align}
For your example we set $p=5, q=3$
Though I don't know where you could look for a proof.

I like this idea very much - if there was a simple proof it would be perfect.

@Red Five The proof I gave for $15=3\times 5$ works for any $n=p\times q$.

For the second question, apply the formula $$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=2\cos \frac {\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos \frac {\alpha-\beta}{2}$$ to the first and third term and to the second and the forth term:
$$\cos{\frac{2\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{4\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{8\pi}{15}}+\cos{\frac{14\pi}{15}}=2\cos \frac {10\pi}{30}\cos \frac {6\pi}{30}+2\cos \frac {18\pi}{30}\cos \frac {10\pi}{30}$$
and then you get
$$2\cos \frac {\pi}{3}\left(\cos \frac {\pi}{5}+\cos \frac {3\pi}{5}\right)=\cos \frac {\pi}{5}+\cos \frac {3\pi}{5}=\cos \frac {\pi}{5}-\cos \frac {2\pi}{5}.$$
Now, to evaluate $\cos \frac {\pi}{5}-\cos \frac {2\pi}{5}$, let $x$ be $\cos \frac {\pi}{5}$ and $y$ be $\cos \frac {2\pi}{5}$. From $\cos 2\alpha=2\cos^2 \alpha-1$ you get $y=2x^2-1$; observing that $\cos \frac{4\pi}{5}=-x$, from the same formula you get $x=1-2y^2$. Now
$$x+y=2x^2-2y^2=2(x+y)(x-y).$$
As $x+y\neq 0$, then $1=2(x-y)$ and
$$\cos \frac {\pi}{5}-\cos \frac {2\pi}{5}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
