# Proving $2\cos36° = 2\sin18° +1$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Please tell me if there is a duplicate; I can't find any question that does answer me; If you find one, I'll remove my question. Thank you :)

---

> Prove that $2\cos36° = 2\sin18° +1$.

I saw people proving it by identities [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-solve-cos-36-sin-18-1-2), or I can also prove it by finding the exact value [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml) and [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-the-value-of-sin18%C2%B0-1), but what I'm trying to find is a way that (I hope) can be proven from this diagram, since both $\cos36°$ and $\sin18°$ have a close relationship with the golden ratio. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: This diagram]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Comment: @labbhattacharjee no that does not answer my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull it off with your diagram, but you will also need 
$\color{blue}{\Phi^2=\Phi+1}$ (which is already implied in your diagram).

Take one of the isoceles triangles with sides $\Phi$, $\Phi$ and $1$; split it in half to obtain a right-angled triangle with sides $\Phi$, "something" and $1/2$; then you can compute
$$\sin 18^\circ =\frac{1/2}{\Phi}$$
so that
$$2\sin 18^\circ +1 =\frac{1}{\Phi} +1 =\frac{\color{blue}{1+\Phi}}{\Phi} =\frac{\color{blue}{\Phi^2}}{\Phi} =\Phi.$$

For $\cos 36^\circ$, take an isoceles triangle of sides $\Phi$, $\Phi$ and $\Phi^2$; split it in half to obtain a right-angled triangle with sides $\Phi$, "something" and $\Phi^2/2$; then you can compute
$$\cos 36^\circ =\frac{\Phi^2/2}{\Phi} =\frac{\Phi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the top vertex be called $A$, the left arm vertex be called $B$, the next line intersection on that very horizontal line be called $C$ the center point be called $D$, the next line intersection there be called $E$ and the right arm point be called $F$.

Then you already displayed that $AB=\Phi^2$. Thus from the triangle $ABD$ you get
$$2\cos(36°)=2\frac{BD}{AB}=\frac{BF}{AB}=\frac{\Phi^3}{\Phi^2}=\Phi$$

On the other hand you have displayed that $AC=\Phi$. Thus
$$2\sin(18°)=2\cos(72°)=2\frac{CD}{AC}=\frac{CE}{AC}=\frac1{\Phi}$$

And of course you know that $\Phi=1+1/\Phi$ or (multiplied by $\Phi$): $\Phi^2=\Phi+1$. In fact this can be also read off from the isoceles triangle $ABE$, because $AB=\Phi^2$ and $AB=BE=BC+CE=\Phi+1$.

--- rk