# Proving that $\sin(54°)\sin(66°) = \sin(48°)\sin(96°)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to prove that $\sin(54°)\sin(66°) = \sin(48°)\sin(96°)$ but I don't really have a way to approach it. Most of what I tried was replacing $\sin(2x)$ with $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ or changing sines with cosines but none of that has really simplified it.

Would appreciate any solution.

Comment: Maybe this helps: $66=60+6$, $54=60-6$, $96=90+6$, $48=60-2\cdot 6$.

Comment: Using that we get to prove $\dfrac{1}{4}(3\cos^2(6°) - \sin^2(6°)) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(cos^2(6°)-\sin^2(6°))\cos(6°) - \sin(6°)cos^2(6°)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LHS is
$$
\sin(54)\sin(66)=\cos(36)\cos(24). 
$$
The RHS is
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(48)\sin(96)&=2\sin(24)\cos(24)\sin(96)=\cos(24)\big(\cos(72)-\cos(120)\big)=\\
&=\cos(24)\left(\cos(72)+\frac12\right).
\end{align}
$$
Thus, proving that LHS=RHS is equivalent to proving that
$$
\color{red}{\cos(36)-\cos(72)=\frac12}.
$$
The cosine values in the last identity are related to the [golden section via the regular pentagon](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml) as
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(36)&=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4},\\
\cos(72)&=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4},
\end{align}
$$
which makes the red identity true.

P.S. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2).

Answer (score 1):

Using degrees as a measure unit,
$$ \sin(60+6)\sin(60-6) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(12)-\cos(10\cdot 12)\right)$$
and
$$ \sin(4\cdot 12)\sin(8\cdot 12) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(4\cdot 12)-\cos(12\cdot 12)\right)$$
hence the problem boils down to proving that
$$\cos(12)-\cos(48)+\cos(144)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
or, reverting to radians, proving that $x=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}\right)$ is a root of the polynomial
$$ 1+2\,T_1(x)-2\,T_4(x)+2\,T_{12}(x)\\=\color{red}{1 + 2 x - 128 x^2 + 1664 x^4 - 7168 x^6 + 13824 x^8 - 12288 x^{10} + 
 4096 x^{12}}. $$
Since the minimal polynomial of $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{30}\right)$ is $\color{blue}{1 - 8 x - 16 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4}$, it is enough to check that the blue polynomial is a divisor of the red polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin54^\circ=\cos36^\circ$  and $$\sin48^\circ=2\cos24^\circ\sin24^\circ$$

the proposition reduces to $$\cos36^\circ=2\sin24^\circ\sin96^\circ=\cos(96-24)^\circ-\cos(96+24)^\circ=\cos72^\circ-\left(-\dfrac12\right)$$

Now use [How do we prove $\cos(\pi/5) - \cos(2\pi/5) = 0.5$ ?.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130817/how-do-we-prove-cos-pi-5-cos2-pi-5-0-5/1861116#1861116)