# Given that $w = e^{(2\pi/5)i}$, show that $w + \overline{w}$ is a root > of $z^2 + z - 1 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Hoping to get some help with the following problem

> Given that $w = e^{(2\pi/5)i}$, show that $w + \overline{w}$ is a root
>   of $z^2 + z - 1 = 0$.

I've noticed that $w + \overline{w} = 2Re(w)$, but I'm not sure on how to proceed from there. $2\pi/5$ is a weird angle, so substituting a cosine doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove $\cos \frac{2\pi }{5}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-prove-cos-frac2-pi-5-frac-1-sqrt54)

Comment: Note that $w^4 = \bar{w}, w^3 = \bar{w^2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat:  The calculation of $\cos(2\pi/5)$ will certainly do it, but I think of the two problems as having different "natural" solutions. Why not answer?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I added my take on it below, I'm not sure that this is what you were thinking. (My answer isn't really any different than that in the linked answer?)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $w^4 = \overline{w}$, $w^3 = \overline{w^2} = \overline{w}^2$.

We have $1+w+w^2+w^3+w^4 = {1-w^5 \over 1 -w} = 0$.

That is, $1 + (w + \overline{w}) + (w^2 + \overline{w}^2) = 1 + (w + \overline{w}) + (w + \overline{w})^2 -2 = (w + \overline{w})^2 + (w + \overline{w}) -1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$w + \overline{w} = 2\cos (2\pi/5)$, and $(2\cos (2\pi/5))^2 + 2\cos (2\pi/5) - 1 = 4\left(\dfrac{1+\cos (4\pi/5)}{2}\right) + 2\left(2\cos^2(\pi/5) - 1\right) - 1 = 2\left(1-\cos (\pi/5)\right) + 4\cos^2(\pi/5) - 2 - 1 = 4\cos^2(\pi/5) - 2\cos (\pi/5) - 1 = S$.

We have: $\cos 36^\circ = \sin 54^\circ$ gives: $1-2x^2 = 3x - 4x^3$ with $x = \sin 18^\circ = \sin (\pi/10)$. Thus: $4x^3 - 2x^2 - 3x + 1 = 0 \to (x-1)(4x^2 + 2x - 1) = 0$. Since $0 < x < 1$, $4x^2 + 2x - 1 = 0$. Thus : $\cos (\pi/5) = 1 - 2x^2 = 1 - \dfrac{1-2x}{2} = \dfrac{1+2x}{2}$, and $\cos^2(\pi/5) = \left(\dfrac{1+2x}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1+4x+4x^2}{4} = \dfrac{1+4x+1-2x}{4} = \dfrac{1+x}{2}$. Thus: $S = 4\left(\dfrac{1+x}{2}\right) - 2\left(\dfrac{1+2x}{2}\right) - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We may treat $ \ w \ = \ e^{i·2\pi/5} \ $ and $ \ \overline{w} \ = \ e^{-i·2\pi/5} \ $ as unit vectors in the complex plane, as seen in the graph above. Placing them head-to-tail, they then form two sides of an isosceles triangle in which their vector sum $ \ w + \overline{w} \ $ is the third side lying in the real-axis.  We shall call the length of that side $ \ z_1 \ \ ; $ as the apex angle of this triangle has measure $ \ \pi/5 \ \ , $ we have  $ z_1^2 \ = \ 1^2 + 1^2 - 2·1·1·\cos \frac{\pi}{5} \ = \ 2·(1 - \cos \frac{\pi}{5} )\ \ . $

If we employ the cosine-squared identity, we may also write
$$ \ \left(\cos \frac{2\pi}{5} \right)^2 \ = \ \frac12 · \left(1 \ + \ \cos \frac{4\pi}{5} \right) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left(2 · \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} \right)^2 \ = \ 2 · \left(1 \ + \ \cos \frac{4\pi}{5} \right) \ \ , $$
and, since $ \ \cos \frac{4\pi}{5} = -\cos \frac{\pi}{5} \ \ , $
$$  \left(2 · \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} \right)^2 \ = \ 2 · \left(1 \ - \ \cos \frac{\pi}{5} \right) \ = \ z_1^2 \ \ . $$
(We also see this in that $ \  \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} \ $ is one-half of the base of the isosceles triangle.)

[image]

We can find the trigonometric values of interest from dissection of a unit regular pentagon (as mentioned on this site going back to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-prove-cos-frac2-pi-5-frac-1-sqrt54)).  By drawing in two diagonals of the pentagon, which has interior angles $ \ \frac{3\pi}{5} \ \ , $ we form a unit parallelogram and two sets of similar triangles.

The isosceles triangle we have been discussing appears here, for instance, as $ \ \Delta ABF \ \ , $ with unit sides and base $ \ x \ \ . $  The other type of isosceles triangle is represented by $ \ \Delta ABC \sim \Delta CFB \ \ . $  Between those triangles, we can set up the proportionality $$ \frac{x}{1} \ = \ \frac{1}{1 \ + \ x} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x·(1 \ + \ x) \ = \ 1 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ z^2 \ + \ z \ -  \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
which is the equation for which we are seeking roots.  So one of these is $ \ z_1 \ = \  2 · \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} \ \ . $

We have demonstrated the proposition of the problem, but we can say rather more.  A basic relation for the "golden ratio" $ \ \phi \ $ (some people prefer $ \ \tau \ $) is $ \ \frac{1}{\phi} + 1 \ = \ \phi \ \ ; $  returning to $ \ x·(1 \ + \ x) \ = \ 1 \ \ , $ we find $ \ \frac{1}{\phi}·\left(1 \ + \ \frac{1}{\phi} \right) \ = \ \frac{1}{\phi}·\phi \ = 1 \ \ . $  Applying the quadratic formula to $ \ z^2  +  z  -  1  \ =  \ 0 \ \ , $ we obtain $ \ x \ = \ \frac{-1 \ \pm \ \sqrt5}{2} \ \ . $  The positive root of the quadratic equation then tells us that
$$ z_1 \ \ = \ \ 2 · \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\phi} \ \ = \ \ \frac{-1 \ + \ \sqrt5}{2} \ \ \approx \ \ 0.61803 \ \ . $$

The *other* root of this quadratic equation is also contained in the golden-ratio relation:
$$ \frac{1}{\phi} + 1 \ = \ \phi \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  1 - \phi \ = \ -\frac{1}{\phi}  \ \ ; $$ $$ x·(1 \ + \ x) \ = \ 1 \ \ , \  \ \text{so}  \ -\phi·(1 \ - \ \phi ) \ = \ -\phi·\left(-\frac{1}{\phi} \right) \ = 1 \ \ . $$

This corresponds to the unit vector sum $  \ v + \overline{v} \ \ ,  $ with
$ \ v \ = \ e^{i·4\pi/5} \ \ , $ in the graph at the top and $ \ \Delta ABC \ $ in the pentagon diagram.  The second root is then
$$ z_2 \ \ = \ \ 2 · \cos \frac{4\pi}{5} \ \ = \ \ -\phi \ \ = \ \ \frac{-1 \ - \ \sqrt5}{2} \ \ \approx \ \ -1.61803 \ \ . $$

By similar reasoning, we can also find the roots of $ \ z^2 \ - \ z \ -  \ 1 \  =  \ 0 \ \ . $  Writing $ \ z·(z \ - \ 1) \ = \ 1 \ $ and the golden-ratio relation as $ \ \phi - 1 \ = \ \frac{1}{\phi} \ \ , $ we obtain
$$  u \ = \ e^{i·\pi/5} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ z'_1 \ \ = \ \ 2 · \cos \frac{\pi}{5} \ \ = \ \ \phi \ \ = \ \ \frac{+1 \ + \ \sqrt5}{2} \ \ 
$$
and
$$  s \ = \ e^{i·3\pi/5} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ z'_2 \ \ = \ \ 2 · \cos \frac{3\pi}{5} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{1}{\phi} \ \ = \ \ \frac{+1 \ - \ \sqrt5}{2} \ \ , $$
as depicted in the graph below.

[image]