# Showing $\cos\frac{2 \pi}{5}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}=-\frac12$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to show that
$$\cos\frac{2 \pi}{5}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}=-\frac12,\,\cos(2 \pi/5)\cos(4 \pi/5)=-1/4$$.
I can't use the value of $\cos(2 \pi/5)$ without having proven it first.

It's a lot harder than I anticipated, so I thought why not ask here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Showing your efforts at answering the question helps others help you.

Comment: Are complex numbers allowed?

Comment: Hint:
$$1+\cos\frac{2\pi}5+\cos\frac{4\pi}5+\cos\frac{6\pi}5+\cos\frac{8\pi}5=0.
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the top answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-prove-cos-frac2-pi-5-frac-1-sqrt54)

if $z = e^{2 i \pi /5}$ or $e^{4 i \pi/5}$
then
$\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$ is equal to the corresponding value of cos in either case

and $1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 = 0$ also in either case, so dividing through by $z^2$ shows that our values both satisfy $w^2 + \frac{w}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = 0$.

At which point we are done by [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) [suppose the roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and expand $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$]

Comment: I've tried solving it through the complex definition of the cosine, but I couldn't show that $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$. Is there a proof you can point me to?

Comment: @NikoGruben Note $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=(1-z^5)/(1-z)$, and since $z$ is a fifth root of unity, this is zero

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using roots of unity $z^5=1$ we get $z=\cos\frac{2k\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{5}, k=0,1,2,3,4$. 
Using Vieta theorem, it follows that $1+\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{5}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the double angle identity,

\begin{align}
\cos\frac{4\pi}5&=2\cos^2\frac{2\pi}5 - 1\tag1\\
\cos\frac{2\pi}5=\cos\frac{8\pi}5&=2\cos^2\frac{4\pi}5 - 1\tag2
\end{align}

$(1)-(2):$
$$\cos\frac{4\pi}5-\cos\frac{2\pi}5=2\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}5+\cos\frac{4\pi}5\right)\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}5-\cos\frac{4\pi}5\right)$$
$$\therefore\quad\cos\frac{2\pi}5+\cos\frac{4\pi}5=-\frac12$$